# What is a combinatorial meaning of the sum?

Tags: combinatorics, reference-request, integer-partitions

Let us consider a partition $1^{j_1} 2^{j_2} \cdots n^{j_n}$ of $n$  i.e. $j_1+2 j_2+\cdots + n j_n =n$.  It iseasy to see that the sum $j_1+j_2+\cdots+j_n$  is just the length of the partition.

**Question.**  Is there any  combinatorial meaning or  closed form of the two sums 
$$
j_1^2+2 j_2^2+\cdots + n j_n^2
$$
and 
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n \sum_{i=1}^{k-1} gcd(k,i) j_k j_i?
$$

Comment: Is there any motivation behind these sums?

Answer (score 1):

Just some initial observation about the first sum.
$$j^2_1+2j^2_2+\dots+nj^2_n = j_1+2j_2+\dots+nj_n = n$$
exactly when the partition parts are distinct.  Otherwise the sum with squares is giving some weighted measure of repeated parts.

$$\begin{array}{cc}
\text{partition} & \text{sum with squares} \\ \hline
(2,2) & 8 \\
(2,1,1) & 6 \\
(1,1,1,1) & 16 \\ \hline
(3,1,1) & 7 \\
(2,2,1) & 9 \\
(2,1,1,1) & 11 \\
(1,1,1,1,1) & 25 \\ \hline
\end{array}$$

The sequence of $j_1+2^2j_2+\dots+n^2j_n$ summed over all partitions of $n$ (that is, the sum of all parts squared in all partitions of $n$) is http://oeis.org/A066183, but the sequence of sum of $j^2_1+2j^2_2+\dots+nj^2_n$ summed over all partitions of $n$ isn't there. (I believe it starts $1,6,15,38,67$---comparing this to $n\cdot p(n)$, i.e., $1, 4, 9, 20, 35$, could say something about the repeated parts among all partitions of $n$...)